# How to store a Tree Of Life in MySQL? (Phylum, Class, Order, Family, etc)

Tags: mysql, data-structures, tree, multi-level

(Seems that I cannot recover my previous SE account)

I'm currently trying to make a database with the tree of life and I was wondering what would be the best approach to such a thing since it's quite huge and still evolving.

The levels (for those unfamiliar with this) are the following

```
Kingdom
Phylum
  SubPhylum (may be empty)
Class
  SubClass (may be empty)
Order
  SubOrder (may be empty)
Family
    SubFamily (may be empty)
  Tribe (may be empty)
    SubTribe (may be empty)
Genus
    SubGenus (may be empty)
  Section (may be empty)
    SubSection (may be empty)
  Series (may be empty)
    SubSeries (may be empty)
Species
    SubSpecies (may be empty)
  Variety (may be empty)
    SubVariety (may be empty)
  Form (may be empty)
    SubForm
```

(Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank)

My first idea was to make a single table with everything inside like this:

```
Class         Order         Family       Genus     Species
Actinop[...]  
Actinop[...]  Silurif[...]
Actinop[...]  Silurif[...]  Callich[...]
Actinop[...]  Silurif[...]  Callich[...] Corydoras 
Actinop[...]  Silurif[...]  Callich[...] Corydoras C. aeneus
```

Lots of duplicate data and can get very heavy. [...] used to make things shorter here.

So I though that I could do a table for each type:

Table **Phylum** :

```
phylum_name phylum_id kingdom_id
```

Table **Class** :

```
class_name class_id phylum_id kingdom_id
```

Table **ClassSub** :

```
subclass_name subclass_id class_id phylum_id kingdom_id
```

[...]

Table **Species**

```
 species_name species_id subgenus_id genus_id subtribe_id tribe_id subfamily_id family_id superfamily_id
```

Third approach:

Table **TreeOfLife**

```
 id   name            levelnumber          levelname  parentid   commonname
 1    Animalia        1                    kingdom    NULL
 2    Chordata        2                    phylum     1
 ...
 7    Corydoras       7                    genus      6
 8    Corydoras leucomelas  8              species    7        False spotted catfish
```

You get the concept. The goal here is to have a multi-level dropdown and once the user get to, let's say, the family, if the family isn't there, he can add it, add it's subfamily (if present), then the genus required to that family, then the species and add a picture of it (or whatever)

If the family **Callichthyidae** is present, he can then add the **Corydoradinae** subfamily and the **Corydoras** genus. Then he can add a species and a picture.

What would be the best approach to save diskspace and speed up SELECT queries? I've never worked with such complicated multi-level data and I would very much appreciate the help of the community.

Thanks!

Comment: For a structure like this, you'd probably be far better off with  MongoDB than my SQL.

Comment: Try Couchbase and N1QL.

Comment: I found this to be useful, basically a self-referential table: http://web.utah.edu/cms/whitepapers/ImplementingaTaxonomy.pdf